# Is the PHP ReflectionClass a singleton?

Tags: php, performance, reflection

I have a need to get the ReflectionClass instance of a class from a few different places in my code. I was going to manage a singleton instance of it myself for performance reasons. However, I thought PHP may already do this.

If you new up a ReflectionClass for the same class multiple times, does PHP manage the singleton for you or do any other kind of caching?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, reflectionClass is not a singleton; nor does it have any intelligence "built in" to act as a singleton if you try to instantiate multiple reflectionClass instances for the same class/object. Each instance of reflectionClass is totally autonomous

Comment: Could you explain this singleton with reflection?http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstancewithoutconstructor.php#105670

Comment: @iLen it just disables *constructor* and *clone* methods on every class that ```use```s the trait; so you can just use ```getInstance()``` to retrieve the single instance calling the ```__construct``` that is eventually defined in the ```use```ing class. Only difference is that calls the *contructor* later after the first instantiation (feels like the *Javascript* way: first copy the prototype of the function/class and then apply the execution of the *constructor* function/method. IMHO, it works but is not so much OOP way). It basically generalizes so you can make every class a *singleton*.